# How to go back to previous page on page reload

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

How to go back to previous page when user clicks the reload button on the browser?
Tried with window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(event) inside created() but it shows an alert message which I do not want to show.

```
        window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(event) {
        event.returnValue = "Write something";
        window.history.go(-1);
        });
```

Comment: You should not go to the previous page when the user reloads. That is a usibility issue. Rather make your site work even if the user reloads the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you set a cookie and put a value in it like for example

```
hasopened = true
```

then when your page opens you can read the cookie and act accordingly.

```
    <script>
    window.addEventListener("load", afterLoaded,false);

   function afterLoaded(){  <!-- below are just samples -->
                          <!-- alert("after load");  ---> 
                           <!-- lookForCityChange(); -->
                      <!--    over here you'd want to read the cookie. -->
                       }
    
       function lookForCityChange() <!-- want to click the button -->
   {   
       <!-- window.location.replace('audiorecover.html');  --->
       <!--   document.getElementById("ASongx").click(); -->
       <!--    alert("Document...");     -->
   }          
    </script>
```